# Under what circumstances does an update Join table work without a FROM statement in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure out the cases where these two statements work or do not work. I was able to use statement 1 a couple times for a project; however I cannot decipher the difference. 
STATEMENT 1

```
UPDATE tbl1 AS a INNER JOIN tbl2 as b where a.clm = b.clm
SET
    a.clm1 = 
    CASE
        WHEN b.clm2 = 1 THEN 11
        ELSE 2
    END,
  b.clm2 = 
    CASE
        WHEN b.clm4 = 2 THEN 3
        ELSE 100
    END;
```

compared to

STATEMENT 2

```
UPDATE a
SET
a.clm1 = 
    CASE
        WHEN b.clm2 = 1 THEN 11
        ELSE 2
    END,
  b.clm2 = 
    CASE
        WHEN b.clm4 = 2 THEN 3
        ELSE 100
    END
FROM tbl1 AS a INNER JOIN tbl2 as b where a.clm = b.clm;
```

Comment: I've always used the general syntax of you second example with success.

Comment: Perhaps you were using MySQL with the first query.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement 1 should throw an error on compile. [update syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)

Update always has to be followed by the object being updated.  Otherwise, SQL Server would have no idea which table in a join is the one that needs to be updated.

If you refer to the link to the msdn article, you'll see the syntax requires the following:

1. Update [alias or object name]
2. Set statement
3. From (if you used an alias)
4. Where statement

As jonnyGold said, your second example is the ideal way to do an update with a join or any complex queries.  For simple queries, you can just do "update [object] set...where...".